# Image control in wpf application doesn't show image properly

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I have distorted image if actual image's size is larger than control's property. For example: image is 800 x 600, control is only 200 x 200.

```
System.Windows.Controls.Image im = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
im.Stretch = Stretch.None ;
im.Width = 200;
im.Height = 200;
im.Margin = new Thickness(5, 5, 5, 5);
im.Source = loadImageFromArray(m_imgs[f]);

private BitmapSource loadImageFromArray(Byte[] imageData)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageData))
    {
        var decoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(ms,
            BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnDemand);
        return decoder.Frames[0];
    }
}
```

Tried to play with Image.Stretch but none of it's values doesn't give proper display. I want control to resize image without cropping and display it. Images are in jpeg format.

VS2013, WPF, netfw 4.0.

UPD: sorry guys, but I found the answer. Problem contains in BitmapCacheOptions. With BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad all works great. Don't know why OnDemand works properly only with small images. Will post is as answer.

Comment: See the Remarks section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615998.aspx) for an explanation why you have to use `OnLoad` when loading a BitmapFrame from a stream which is to be closed right after loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in cache option. As Clemens pointed out, we need to choose `OnLoad` cache option if you wish to close the `bitmapStream` after the bitmap is created.

Answer (score 0):

When you set [`Uniform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.stretch(v=vs.110).aspx) The content is resized to fit in the destination dimensions while it preserves its native aspect ratio.

```
   System.Windows.Controls.Image im = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
   im.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
   im.MaxHeight = 200;
   im.MaxWidth = 200;
```